# Array to string conversion in array index as parameter

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to pass this parameter `$this->settings['dateFormat']` that have this valorization:

> d-m-Y G:i:s.u

to this function:

```
getTimeStamp($this->settings['dateFormat']);
```

but I get:

> Array to string conversion

but if I workaround the problem like this.

```
$temp = $this->settings['dateFormat'];
getTimeStamp($temp);
```

no error is displayed.. So, how I can pass directly the `dateFormat` index without create each time the variable `$temp`?

Comment: I am not sure but try to cast it as string such as getTimeStamp((string)$this->settings['dateFormat']);

Comment: what does the `getTimeStamp` function do ?

Comment: @DiegoMariani return a date with the custom format passed in a settings array. Also the cast not working

Comment: `getTimeStamp` is not a default PHP function, right?

Comment: please provide more information, paste your code `getTimeStamp ` and `var_dump($this->settings['dateFormat'])`

Comment: @Sandoken, is getTimeStamp() created as your custom function or you are using function of PHP ?